# Нажатие клавиш питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

У меня не работает нажатие клавиш библиотеки keyboard для python. Код простой и функция выполняется, но само нажатие не происходит. В чём может быть проблема?

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('Ctrl'):
        keyboard.send('win+d')
        print('Complete!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

вместо `send` напишите `press`

```py
import keyboard
while True:
    keyboard.wait("ctrl")
    keyboard.send("win+d")
    print("Complete!")
    break
```